# Firebase notifications programmatically? objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase for a project and I want to use push notifications.

Is there a way to send a push notification to all users of my app from code, i.e. not using the console?

I accomplished this using Cloudkit with CKSubscritpitons, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do a similar thing in Firebase.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO as it is primarily opinion based question.

Comment: have you got the solution ? i guess yes . can you please guide me through it ? because i am also working on same scenario . i am calling the firebase to send notifications through web-service . but i am not getting any . manually from firebase , i am getting perfectly . help me with this issue , if you had figured it out already .

Comment: Hi Moxarth, I found two solutions to this problem: 1) sign up for a third party service like OneSignal (which is awesome), or 2) use firebase functions and call a POST request from your app with the FIRMessaging token.

Answer (score 3):

### Integrate without CocoaPods

**First Read Firebase Doc.** => [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available_pods)

1. Register project on Firebase here => [Register Project here](https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1)
2. Get GoogleService-Info.plist file from here=> project=> settings => General
3. GoogleService-Info.plist file drop in your project.
4. set Notification .p12 Certificates (Production and Development) in Firebase
    => project=> settings => Cloud Messaging
5. Download Firebase SDK here => [Firebase SDK Download](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available_pods)
6. Create SDK folder in your project and Drop all SDK Folder in it.
7. Now Add this Framework in your Xcode => libicucore.tbd
8. Set Background Modes ON in Xcode => Projects => Capabilities => Background Mode ON => RemoteNotification
9. Add in your Info.Plist file **FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled** Set BOOL **NO**.

[image]

In Objective-c
your Appdelegate.m file

```html
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Firebase.h"
#import "AFNHelper.h"

@interface AppDelegate (){

    NSString *InstanceID;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strUUID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strDeviceToken;
@end
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    [FIRApp configure];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    NSLog(@"userInfo=>%@", userInfo);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];
    NSLog(@"deviceToken1 = %@",deviceToken);

}
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
   NSLog(@"instanceId_notification=>%@",[notification object]);
    InstanceID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[notification object]];

 [self connectToFcm];  
}

- (void)connectToFcm {

[[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } else {

        NSLog(@"InstanceID_connectToFcm = %@", InstanceID);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self sendDeviceInfo];
                NSLog(@"instanceId_tokenRefreshNotification22=>%@",[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]);

            });
        });


    }
}];}
```

Comment: i have followed all the steps but fails to understand one procedure . when i am sending message from firebase manually , i get the notification and message as well, but when i call firebase to send notification through web-service , i am not getting any notifications nor any messages . same scenario with android is working fine . so for ios , what and which methods should i use more ? am i missing some other features to follow ? please help me with this .

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but would you mind pointing out where in your code you are sending a message via push notification? It appears to be me that you have only registered to receive push notifications.

Answer (score 2):

The [Notifications Console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) is for sending notifications to groups of users.

If you want to programmatically send notifications, have a look at [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). This will require you to run code in a trusted process (e.g. a server).

Comment: i have followed all the steps but fails to understand one procedure . when i am sending message from firebase manually , i get the notification and message as well, but when i call firebase to send notification through web-service , i am not getting any notifications nor any messages . same scenario with android is working fine . so for ios , what and which methods should i use more ? am i  missing some other features to follow ? please help me with this .